# How to pass a property or thread group variable to sample_variables=<variable_name>

Tags: jmeter

I would like to add a variable from thread group 1 as a custom field to the jtl file for lines reported by thread group 2 by using the property sample_variables=.
Tried w making a property of the local variable from Thread Group 1 but sample_variables don't seem to print properties.

Is it anyway I can log a variable from Thread Group 1 for every execution in Thread Group 2?

```
Test Plan (initiated w property sample_variables=var1)
--> Thread Group 1
----> JDBC request setting var1   # this prints var1 nicely to the jtl file
--> Thread Group 2
---> Another JDBC request   # this prints "null" to jtl (as var1 is local to TG1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property you instruct JMeter to save the defined variable(s) value(s) into extra column(s) in the .jtl results file
2. According to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions):

   > Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

If you just want to copy a single value from the Thread Group 1 to Thread Group 2 you need to:

- Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the end of the Thread Group 1
- Put the following code into "Script" area:

  ```
  prev.setIgnore() //don't save this JSR223 Sampler in listeners or .jtl result file
  props.put('var1', vars.get('var1')) // convert var1 variable into a JMeter property
  ```
- Add JSR223 Sampler to the beginning of the Thread Group 2
- Put the following code into "Script" area:

  ```
  prev.setIgnore()
  vars.put('var1',props.get('var1')) // convert var1 property into a JMeter Variable
  ```

In the above code `props` is an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.